# Listening UITextField in the background even if the app or keyboard extension is not active

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, keyboard-events, uitextfielddelegate

How can I write an application that listens to the text field in messaging applications such as Whatsapp, iMessage and captures the entries according to a predetermined format (for example: there is a * character at the beginning and end of the word)? The app or function should run in the background. Can we do it without the keyboard extension or even if the app or keyboard extension is not active?

Comment: If to rephrase your question, “is there a privacy breach in iOS that I can exploit?” Last 0day I know of was working till it got fixed in iOS 13.5.

Comment: hi Euegene, I could use the vulnerabilities related to processing keys entered on the keyboard by listening, but you say that apple has closed those gaps, as far as I understand? Thank you.

Comment: No, the gap that I mean was different. If interested, https://siguza.github.io/psychicpaper